# nestjs and typeorm - failing to setup the dependency injection

Tags: typescript, dependency-injection, nestjs

I am trying to use `nestjs` and `typeorm` to write a basic CRUD application working but I am failing to get the dependency injection working. I am trying to put the code setups the database into separate modules and import it.

This is the error I am getting:

> [ExceptionHandler] Nest can't resolve dependencies of the
>   QuestionController (?). Please make sure that the argument at index
>   [0] is available in the current context. +14ms 4:
>   v8::internal::MaybeHandle
>   v8::internal::(anonymous
>   namespace)::HandleApiCallHelper(v8::internal::Isolate*,
>   v8::internal::Handle,
>   v8::internal::Handle,
>   v8::internal::Handle,
>   v8::internal::Handle,
>   v8::internal::BuiltinArguments) [/usr/local/bin/node]

This is the basic code structure:

`database.module.ts`

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
      type: 'sqlite',
      database: 'database.sqlite',
    }),
  ],
})
export class DatabaseModule {
}
```

`question.module.ts`:

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    DatabaseModule,
    TypeOrmModule.forFeature([Question]),
  ],
  providers: [QuestionDal, QuestionLogic],
})
export class QuestionModule {
}
```

`app.module.ts`

```
@Module({
  imports: [QuestionModule],
  controllers: [QuestionController],
  providers: [],
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

`question.dal.ts`

```
@Injectable()
export class QuestionDal {

  constructor(@InjectRepository(Question) private questionRepo: Repository<Question>) { }

}
```

`question.logic.ts`

```
@Injectable()
export class QuestionLogic {
  constructor(private questionDal: QuestionDal) { }
}
```

`question.controller.ts`

```
@Controller()
export class QuestionController {
  constructor(private readonly appService: QuestionLogic) { }

}
```

I appreciate any help or hint

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to export the `QuestionLogic` provider inside the `QuestionModule`.

You will be able to inject it in others modules importing the `QuestionModule`.

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    DatabaseModule,
    TypeOrmModule.forFeature([Question]),
  ],
  providers: [QuestionDal, QuestionLogic],
  exports: [QuestionLogic] 
})
export class QuestionModule {
}
```